# How to display the images in three different folder in same tag

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $sql=mysql_query(
"SELECT ssmid, image FROM user_photos_offline WHERE ssmid='$ssmid' AND status='1'
UNION
SELECT ssmid, image FROM user_profile_pic WHERE ssmid='$ssmid' AND status='1'
UNION
SELECT ssmid, image FROM user_family_photos WHERE ssmid='$ssmid' AND status='1' " 
);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 echo  $result = $row['image'];// Here i got all images name from DB
 }
```

This code working fine,$result i am getting all values from DB,But this images i moved three diffrent folders,these are the folders name cropped-images,family-photos,profile-photos
    How to show the image folder name in `<img src='?????'>`

Comment: mysql_* extension was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_* extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used.

Try this

```
$folder_names = array("cropped-images","profile-photos","family-photos");
$i = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo  $result = $row['image'];// Here i got all images name from DB
  echo "<img src='".$folder_names[$i]."/".$result."'>";      
  $i++;
}
```